# Python : Operations on DateTime range intervals

Tags: python, datetime

I have time data in the form of:[ (from , to) , (.. , ..) , ..]

`[('16:35', '16:10'),
 ('18:45', '18:15'),
 ('19:14', '12:15'),
 ('10:36', '00:10'),
 ('21:08', '13:40'),
 ('22:20', '06:10'),
 ('03:20', '16:40'),
 ('23:56', '12:10'),
 ('00:16', '21:30'),`

I need to perform operation like if time range falls within the range > 23:00 & time < 01:15` then I need to flag it. Like, in the case of (21:00, 23:33), it should flag. And, in the case of (02:00, 06:00), it shouldn't flag. Midnight scenario should also be taken care of.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write a function to check if a given tuple is within your range and then use a list comprehension such as

`flagged = [x for x in myList if inMyRange(x)]`

To get a list of all flagged ranges. Or perform an operation on the flagged items in the comprehension itself

`operated = [myOperation(x) for x in myList if inMyRange(x)]`